# If I share my React-Native app do I need to put the ios and android folders into source control?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to build out a React-Native sample app to share with coworkers. When I put it up on github and then clone it into a new folder it won't start:

```
react-native run-ios
ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir
```

I think that's because I have no ios folder. I assumed that when I started the packager it would build this if not present. The docs say that `run-ios` will `builds your app and starts it on iOS simulator`. Appears that this is either not the case or there is a bug. Directory contents after starting the packager:

```
LICENSE
README.md
index.android.js
index.ios.js
node_modules
package.json
```

Is there a "rebuild" command that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You do have to put them. Actually, the `react-native init` should have created a `.gitignore` file with the directories and files that do not have to be included. You can see an example of what it creates in the [sample apps](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.2.1/Examples/SampleApp/.gitignore).

Comment: Is there no way to rebuild those files? If I have the React Native source files in repo the Android and IOS files feel like build artifacts rather than source files.

Comment: I would not say that. React Native works by creating a native app that then executes some Javascript code and provides a bridge between the two. The iOS and Android project files are the mechanism to interact with the underlying OS and platform APIs, so they are an important building block of you app. Besides, it might include certain parts of your code (like custom native modules or simply modifications to the Info.plist/AndroidManifest.xml)  which cannot be inferred from the JavaScript side.